Is there a unitary mapping every state in the upper half of the Bloch sphere to $|0\rangle$?
I am having trouble finding a way to map certain parts of the Bloch sphere to |0> and leave the rest intact. For example, let's think of a state vector
$|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$. What I want is to find a unitary that maps every state that is, let's say, in the upper half of the Bloch sphere, i.e. with $\theta  < \frac{\pi}{2}$ to state $| 0 \rangle$.
Am I correct that finding such a unitary is impossible since such a transformation can't be unitary?

Yes, you are right. Such mapping is not reversible unless the mapping returns both output and input together like in case of Toffoli gate.
